# Insert geometry values in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial, sqlgeometry

I want to insert GEOMETRY values into a table. For which I have a table with three columns as shown below:

**Table**: geo

```
create table geo
(
p1 float,
p2 float,
Paths GEOMETRY
);
```

**Input values**: I have following values

```
p1 = 22.9901232886963
p2 = 87.5953903123242
```

## My bad try:

```
INSERT INTO geo(Paths)
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON (22.9901232886963,87.5953903123242)', 4326));
```

Comment: STGeomFromText is Function ..??

Comment: Right now, your data doesn't make sense. Specifically, what do p1 and p2 represent? Are they the X & Y coordinates of some point? Something else? Also, since it appears that you're specifying an SRID, do you mean to be using the geography datatype instead of geometry?

Comment: @Ben Thul, Yes they are X & Y of the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WKT is malformed. This works for me:

```
declare @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText(
    'POINT (22.9901232886963 87.5953903123242)'
    , 4326);

select @g
```

Note too that it's a point and not a polygon.

Comment: Yeah! This is rigth. But how can I insert x and y that is p1 and p2 in the table with @g?

Comment: Replace your call to STGeomFromText with mine in your original statement.

Comment: What is `4326` for?

Comment: It does have the feel of a magic number, but is a special reference identifier (SRID). You can read about appraisal systems here - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system.